# Chilling 750 ml liquid (wine, water, etc) in 30 seconds by 20 °F?

Tags: thermodynamics, estimation, freezing, liquid-state

There's a crowdfunding campaign which advertises a container like device that you can put in the freezer and after you take it you can pour in 750 ml of liquid and it decreases the temperature of it from room temperature by 20 °F in 30 seconds, so about 11 °C.

They also claim

> The first bottle should take about 30 seconds. Additional bottle may take slightly longer, but still way faster than a fridge or freezer

and

> it will take a few minutes to bring drink to below freezing temperatures.

The liquid is separate from the rest of the device.

The device has no energy source so if it works then something happens in the container surrounding the liquid holder. But what? Are these physically sound claims?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Link?

Comment: This problem is heavily dependent on the particular shape of the container. A container that is itself quite bulky, but only admits a thin tube of liquid, would be able to cool that liquid quite quickly and bring it below freezing without much trouble. But a container with thin walls that has a wider liquid compartment would cool it only very slowly, and might not be able to decrease its temperature much.

Comment: In general, the higher the mass of the container, the lower the final temperature of the liquid (asymptotically approaching the temperature of the freezer). The higher the ratio of liquid surface area to volume, the higher the cooling rate.

Comment: I didn't want to spam that's why I didn't link... https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/prontobev-chill-beverages-in-30-seconds-coffee-tea

Answer (score 1):

I chill wine like that using a thick milk bottle.

The inside surface is stainless steel and uses a proprietary ProntoGel.  The ProntoGel is the coolant with a high heat capacity at a temperature below freezing. The wine is only being cooled to 50 (by 20 degrees).  If the total heat capacity of the ProntoGel 5x the wine it will only warm 4 degrees and if if it undergoes a phase change it will hold that temperature.

> Additional bottle may take slightly longer, but still way faster than
>   a fridge or freezer.

The device has excess thermal capacity compared to a few bottles of wine. An ice chest works just fine with less ice than contents. The key is here is heat transfer rate. It is delta T * area * coefficient.  Water on a sold is very high coefficient.  Stainless steel conducts heat very well.

Liquid on a cool (or hot) surface has fast heat transfer.

There is no glass in between and no dependence on air for heat transfer.

Heat transfer liquid to surface is about 100 times as fast as air to surface as liquid is about 1000 time more dense.  You can put your hand in a 200 degree oven and it just feels warm.  Put your hand in 200 degree water and you will be instantly scaled.

Comment: Canceled the anonymous downvote. Your last two sentences require justification.

Comment: My dear friend, I have a PhD and yet I take time to answer questions and justify my statements.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely possible.

The device itself does not need to do any work.  When you put the device in the freezer, the freezer has to extract the heat from the device, this is where the heat gets expelled.

Once the device is cooled, it acts as a heat sink for the beverage.  The container would likely have a large *surface area* for the fluid inside, and the walls of the container would also have high thermal conductivity.  A series of fins, perhaps with a cool fluid passively circulating (think of the air side of a computer heatsink) would be able to quickly drop the temperature of the liquid.

Air conditioning is done a similar way, air quickly passes over finned heating/cooling coils and is brought to the appropriate temperature.

Comment: I doubt it even need fins.  That would hinder cleaning.

Comment: @Paparazzi Depends on if they built it for serviceability, or to get really high cooling numbers to impress people.  Considering this thing is a black box with no pictures of it's inside, and the only example of "cleaning" is them putting it upside down in a dishwasher, I'm inclined to believe it's not very pretty in there.

Comment: My simple frozen milk bottle will cool in 30 seconds.   I am betting no fins.   If you used orange juice and it did not clean up wine would taste strange.

Comment: I don't see what the taste will have to do with floins really.  You have to clean the container regardless of what it is if you don't want it to taste like the last used fluid.  I also don't know what you're "frozen milk bottle" really is, you need to provide some clearer example/description.

Comment: Not going to a argue with you.   Fins would make cleaning difficult.  It is a "frozen milk bottle".   Same concept.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an analogy to better understand JMac's answer. Heat flux is analogous to water flow, and temperature difference is analogous water-level difference.

Suppose that you often need to empty a particular tank, i.e. bring down the water level in the tank. Someone claims that they have invented an unpowered black box, which when connected to your tank shall bring down the water level by a certain amount in a very short time, compared to that achieved by pumps available on the market. Here pumps are analogous to refrigerators. How does this black-box work? You don't even need hints for this.

Emptying out a tank fast implies that connecting the black-box to the tank achieves very high flow rates, from the tank into black-box. You already know that large flow rates between two connected containers may be achieved if the water level difference between them is large. So the advertised black-box is nothing but an empty tank! However as the black-box fills up, water level difference between black-box and tank decreases continuously, and consequently so does the flow rate. So if the flow rate has to be large all the time so that the tank may be emptied out quickly, then the water level in the black-box should not be allowed to rise quickly. That is easy: all you have to do is make the cross-section (i.e. floor area) of the black-box large compared to that of the tank. Cross-section of the black box is analogous to heat capacity of a body. A body of larger heat capacity has to absorb (or give up) a large amount of heat for its temperature to change appreciably. By using such a black-box with large cross-section it is possible to defeat a pump in the race to empty out a tank.

Of course if you wish to repeatedly use the black box for quickly emptying out the tank, then you need a pump to empty out the black-box, which process is going to take a while. Therefore what time you gained in emptying out the tank quickly using the black-box, is lost in emptying out the black-box to ready it for next time use.

For this entire analogy to be precise in the case of heat transfer, you must imagine your tank to be bottomless but filled with water up to a certain level, and the black-box also to be bottomless but filled with water so that its level is lower than that in the tank.

In summary, the quick-chilling container mentioned in your question must necessarily have a very large heat capacity compared to the liquid which it is intended to cool. Best situation occurs when phase change is involved (loosely speaking a substance undergoing phase change, for e.g. melting ice, has infinite heat capacity; there could be a material lodged in the space between container walls which undergoes phase change; however this poses serious design challenges because phase change is usually associated with large changes in volume of the substance).

Of course since the device has been shown to work, one must suppose that the heat capacity of the container is large enough to handle heat transfer from the ambient as well.  One may further improve the performance of the device by insulating the outer wall of the container, while making the inner wall highly conducting, with vaccuum in between them (like in a Dewar flask) or some other insulating substance. This shall reduce heat gain of the container from the ambient, while increasing heat gain from the liquid placed inside the container. While putting the container in the freezer you must of course uncork it so that the inside of the container may cool down to freezer temperature.

Comment: This answer fail to address a key point.  Why is the device faster than putting the wine bottle in the freezer?

Comment: @Paparazzi That question _is_ answered. I can clarify specific points if you raise them.